# How far off-center can the center be?

Tags: american-football

So sometimes a team can run a play with an [unbalanced line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_football_positions). I was wondering "how unbalanced". Can the center be all the way to one side? Can the center be several yards away from his teammates?

I don't care if it is advisable to do this or not. I'm strictly asking if it is allowed in NFL rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no rules associated with players' distance from the center.  If there was a rule on it, it would be in the rule book.  There are just really three stipulations:

- 7 total players on the line of scrimmage in bounds within the back hip of the center
- the center must hike the ball between his legs
- the ball is set by the referee between the hashes based on the last play (so at most your furthest lineman can be is 2/3 of the field).

I will say that at my high school in the mid 90s we only ran unbalanced and had a future NFL RB go for over 300 yards a game at over a 10 clip.  There is a huge tactical advantage if a defense doesn't rotate correctly or over rotates later in the game.  And just the fact that most defenses don't normally see this.

In fact every once in a while we ran the [swinging gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swinging_gate_(American_football)).  This is a very very very effective play when practiced properly especially just using some basic spread principles (RPO).  If you have a dominant player at a skill position - WR, RB, or QB you can really isolate that player in a 1 on 1 match or make the team double that player at the beginning.

The swinging gate is so effective that most pee-wee to high school rules have stipulations to either outlaw it or make it less effective.  An example is some/most organizations at that level consider the center ineligible and these kinds of formations are why high school rules are so stringent on player numbers for pass catching eligibility.  The actual rules of football allow the center to be eligible if he is at the end of the line of scrimmage.

About 15 years ago I was coaching a 7th grade boys team.  They were not very good but had 3-4 good players.  We had the fastest kid play WR - the lone - player on one side of the center (because the league made me do that).  I had a good QB that could run and a bruiser at RB.  Then I put my fastest lineman at center.

What does a team do?  You have to have a man on my WR.  You also have to have a free safety playing the middle - or we just run a post.

But here is the kicker.  You have to have 3 players minimum - 2 lineman/1 LB or more likely a lineman/2 LBs play against my C/QB/RB.  They better be really really good players.  Because my center will block the closest LB, my QB will read the DL, chances are the DL is so slow he's not even a factor.  Then either I have a one on one for at least 5 yards or I could possibly have a 2-1 if QB beats DL.

So within 5 plays the other coach puts 2 DL (one split wide) and 2 LBs.  Remember there is a CB and FS there too.  So now we have 6 players shading my QB/RB/C/WR.  So then my QB just throws it to the other side and my team is playing 7 on 5.  And my QB can throw it to the other RB and that RB can pass it too.  Since most coaches know their 5 players are screwed they have them rush hard... Flip it to the end and a TD.  The play was banned after the first year we ran it.  Probably average 15 yards a play vs 2 on other plays.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything in the current rules that restrict the positions of the offensive line players with respect to the ball for the purposes of illegal formations.  In addition, there are no restrictions on the distance that line players can be from one another.

So although it would be tactically horrible, it appears to be legal for the rest of the line to play away from the "center" position.  If all the other linemen are on one side, the player would additionally have to report as an eligible receiver beforehand.

Comment: There are *some* restrictions on this coming from the Patriots plays in the 2015 playoffs; see e.g. [this article](http://itiswhatitis.weei.com/sports/newengland/football/patriots/2015/03/25/league-outlaws-patriots-unbalanced-line-approach-that-new-england-used-against-ravens/), although I believe they apply only if normally eligible players are reporting as ineligible.